# The verb "to prioritize"

Tags: глаголы, одним-словом

What is a natural way to say the following?

1. *It's better to give priority to this task.*
2. *I need to set priorities.*
3. *I need to get my priorities straight.*

I'm finding expressions like: (приоритизировать, уделять первоочередное внимание, определить приоритеты), but I'm unable to know whether some are too formal, too literary or unnatural.

Comment: Can't catch what "get" means in the third sentence - do priorities need to be requested in a correct order from a manager, or "I" need to clear up priority order by myself

Comment: @Arhad [**to get straight**](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=get+straight) is a stable collocation

Comment: @Arhad [to get (one's) priorities straight](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+priorities+straight)

Comment: the notion itself isn't a mundane one therefore it tends to always sound formal, the unnatural one is приоритЕзировать, despite its being attested in the Wiktionary, it also doesn't seem to have a standard spelling приоритИ- or приоритЕ-, the rest are OK

Comment: "взяться" and "браться" / "to take on, to engage" - "Мне нужно сначала взяться за эту задачу" / "I need to take on this task first"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Лучше поставить на первое место эту задачу. (informal) OR Лучше дать приоритет этой задаче. (formal)
2. Мне нужно расставить приоритеты.
3. Мне нужно разобраться/определиться с приоритетами.

The word **приоритет** is quite formal so most sentences containing it will probably sound formal.

The expressions "быть в приоритете", "поставить в приоритет" seem to be quite new and are less formal than the word itself. Example:

- У нас сейчас банька в приоритете.

Comment: **сделать задачу** is not Russian, either **сделать задание** (or better **выполнить**) or **решить задачу** (but this is from another opera altogether) or **сделать эту задачу первоочередной** that is to give it a priority

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка, согласен. Влияние буржуазного языка. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

- *It's better to give priority to this task.*

  1. Сто́ит поставить эту задачу в приоритет.
  2. Надо выполнить эту задачу в первую очередь.
- *I need to set priorities.* — я должен расставить приоритеты.

Answer (score 1):

"приоритизировать" is an OK word, it's a bit long, but I definitely heard it used in real life conversations. For more informal statements you can use:

*It's better to give priority to this task.*

Первым делом надо [сделать/закочить/выполнить] [задачу]

For the other two examples you can use "(правильно) расставить приоритеты" if you want to be more formal/literal, but if it's expression along the line of "Hey man, you need to get your priorities straight" you night use something like:

не забывай что тут главное

But like a lot of translation it might depends on context